# Curl error (6) on amazonlinux docker container during `yum install`, but no issues with other image

Tags: curl, docker-compose, dockerfile, amazon-linux, seccomp

I am attempting to build a Docker container on my local machine based on the `amazonlinux:latest` image, but running into a Curl error during the `yum install` steps in my Dockerfile:

```
#6 0.378   - Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host name for https://cdn.amazonlinux.com/al2023/core/mirrors/2023.0.20230322/x86_64/mirror.list [getaddrinfo() thread failed to start]
#6 0.378 Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'amazonlinux': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host name for https://cdn.amazonlinux.com/al2023/core/mirrors/2023.0.20230322/x86_64/mirror.list [getaddrinfo() thread failed to start]
```

The Dockerfile I'm using looks like this:

```
FROM amazonlinux:latest

# Create deploy directory
WORKDIR /deploy

# Install system dependencies
RUN yum -y install make gcc*
# Add NodeSource 10.x yum repository
RUN curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash -
# Install nodejs
RUN yum -y install nodejs

# Install serverless
RUN npm install -g serverless

# Copy source
COPY . .

# Install app dependencies
RUN cd /deploy/functions && npm i --production && cd /deploy

#  Run deploy script
CMD ./deploy.sh ; sleep 2m
```

And my `docker-compose.yml` is:

```
version: "3"
services:
  image-resize-on-the-fly:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./secrets:/deploy/secrets
    env_file:
      - ./secrets/secrets.env
```

Other folks on my team are able to successfully run `docker-compose up --build` with these same files and have no issues. Similarly, I can run commands like `docker run -it centos curl google.com` with a successful response - but running `docker run -it amazonlinux curl google.com` fails with the same Curl error (6) as described above.
Adding `--security-opt seccomp=unconfined` flag to the `amazonlinux` line *DOES* come back with a successful response.

I attempted to use the `unconfined` setting as the default in `~/.docker/daemon.json` by adding `"seccomp-profile":"unconfined"` per (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/) but got back an error saying the `unconfined` profile couldn't be found.

At this point, I'm lost for what to try next. There's clearly some kind of network setup issue, but I'm not well versed enough in those matters to understand what else to look for.

Comment: Can you add where you have installed Docker? Linux/Windows? Seems a DNS problem try to `docker run --dns 8.8.8.8 -it amazonlinux curl google.com` if work try to update the [config.json](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-configuration-file) adding the DNS

Comment: @Max Thanks for your note.
Running on Mac OSX Ventura. I do have a `dns` flag already in my `daemon.json` file, and inspecting the container it does appears to be using `8.8.8.8` as the `namespace`.

Comment: @DerekSchilling I'm sure you've discovered this is about secure computing restrictions - did you find a solution to running docker build based on the amazonlinux docker image?

Answer (score 2):

I'm betting that you're running on a machine where Docker runs with "old" seccomp settings. See this thread for https://github.com/amazonlinux/amazon-linux-2023/issues/80#issuecomment-1017798237 discussion and options.